# Why does the For method of the Parallel class gets faster over time?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logic

I'm doing some testing to find out some duplicates in generated UUID numbers and I use different approaches to execute the calculation. These are `multithreading`, a `normal for loop` and the `for method of the Parallel class`. `Multithreading` is the clear winner, `normal for loop` the looser and the `Parallel.For` method gets faster over time. I've done 10 tests with the `Parallel.For` and it decreased from 18.08 seconds to 11.80 seconds. I'm always starting the project to perform one test at a time, so I believe it can't get stored in memory. And I didn't do anything else on my computer during the test.

These are the test results of the `Parallel.For` method:

```
1: 00:00:18.08
2: 00:00:17.04
3: 00:00:16.79
4: 00:00:15.15
5: 00:00:13.00
6: 00:00:12.69
7: 00:00:12.66
8: 00:00:12.54
9: 00:00:12.33
10: 00:00:11.80
```

Is there any logic explanation for this?

By the way here's the code if it's needed:

```
// In Main
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
            {
                TestForUUIDDuplicates(i + 1);
            });

static void TestForUUIDDuplicates(object loopIndex)
    {
        if (!(loopIndex is int))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }

        var uuids = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 100000 == 0) System.Console.WriteLine("Reached {0} in loop {1}", i, loopIndex);

            uuids.Add(GenerateUUID());
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Finished adding UUIDs in loop {0}.", loopIndex);

        var duplicates = uuids
            .GroupBy(uuid => uuid)
            .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1)).ToList();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Finished finding duplicates in loop {0}.", loopIndex);

        foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(duplicate);
        }

        if (duplicates.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No duplicates found in loop {0}.", loopIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            _duplicates.AddRange(duplicates);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished loop {0}", loopIndex);
    }

    private static string GenerateUUID()
    {
        // var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return ticks.ToString() + '-' + guid;
    }
```

Comment: guesses, but: 1) thread-pool growth (hill-climbing) meaning you have more threads available in the later tests? 2) tiered JIT compilation meaning you're running more aggressively optimized opcodes later?